AngelScript понимание параметров asIScriptEngine::RegisterObjectMethod
В AngelScript при регистрации API приложения нужно указывать calling convention.
Если с asCALL_THISCALL более-менее понятно, то остальные требуют объяснения.
В частности, в чем разница между asCALL_CDECL_OBJLAST и asCALL_CDECL_OBJFIRST?
UPD: Хотелось бы увидеть примеры, что и в каком случае использовать.

Это когда метод класса эмулируется посредством глобальной функции принимающей указатель на экземпляр класса последним либо первым аргументом.

@user7860670 хотелось бы видеть примеры, что и в каком случае использовать.

Ну например когда ты в си вызываешь функцию, а там либо первым, либо последний параметр, указатель на структуру
